# Delphi SetBit-function and TBitRange- type in Java

Tags: java, delphi, encryption

I have to implement the following Delphi function in Java, but anyway the type TBitRange is confusing me. Is there any alternative for this in Java?
Maybe could also anyone explain what this function is doing exactly.

Thanks.

```
const 
     BitsPerByte     = 8;
     BitsPerInteger  = SizeOf(Integer) * BitsPerByte;

type
     TBitRange = Byte;

function SetBit(const Value: Integer; const Bit: TBitRange): Integer;
  begin
     Result := Value or (1 shl (Bit mod BitsPerInteger));
  end;
```

In my Java I implemented this setBit-function as:

```
 static int bitsPerInteger = Integer.SIZE;
    public int setBit(int value, byte bit)
        {
            int result = value | (1 << (bit % bitsPerInteger));
            return result;
        }
```

If I understood in correctly, this function returns the copy of value with the bit at position *bit* set. The *bitsPerInteger* variable is *Integer.SIZE* and is equal to 32. For the test I created two variables: byte bits = 0x34; it's equal 52 as Integer and int value = 4;. The instruction bits % bitsPerInteger; delievers in this case 20 and value | (1 << (bits % bitsPerInteger)) sets the 20th bit of value to 1 and it's equal then to 1048576. So I handed over these two variables as parameters and got then 1048576. Is it right so?

Why its needed to hand over a variable with type *Byte* as parameter for bit-position and then through *mod* -operation get the actually bit-position in bit-String of parameter *value*?. Could we not use an Integer to indicate the bit-position in *value*?

Comment: We cannot guess what that type is. You have the Delphi code. What is it. Of you want to understand Delphi code read the documentation. Have you searched for it?

Comment: You've ignored everything I said in this comment. Why won't you tell us, in an edit to the question, what this mysterious type is? Have you read the documentation that explains what this Delphi code does?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan as Johan said, TBitRange is defined as Byte in my  Delphi encprypt algorithm code. I was a self-defined type for parameter that I hand over to my function.

Comment: I am looking at the question which is the source of information. Nowhere in the question is it stated what type `TBitRange` is. I don't think you are taking any of this seriously. Stack Overflow is not here to be your personal assistant, to do your job for you. We want to build a body of knowledge for future visitors. If we help you along the way, so much the better. If you don't care about building that body of knowledge, and won't edit the question, then we'd rather you looked elsewhere. Please read my second comment above and do what I ask in the second sentence of that comment.

Comment: If that's your question, surely you should ask it in the question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Exactly!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan would you help me please? I've already  improved my Java decryption algrotihm with using `byte[] array` because of 8 bit Delphi `AnsiString` and `AnsiChar`. I invested quite a lot of time, but it still doesn't work. My intership supervisor has also no Idea where I have bug in code because he is not familiar with Java. I read 524 byte of `Hex` repsentation of my encrypted password from `Windows Registry`. After decryption there schould be a character `a` as password. But I'm getting another character as result. Maybe you could look at my code and give me a few advices please? :)

Comment: Do some debugging. Add logging to the internals of the decrypt code. Log intermediate values and compare the Java and Delphi logged values for identical input. Find out where the two versions of the code diverge. If your supervisor does not know how to do such basic debugging then you are in big trouble.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan He is constantly busy with other major tasks. I have already tested the small functions of the Code in Delphi and Java and they deliver the same values. But I can't test the main Delphi function `strDecrypt`. I get always error message on my computer when I try to start it. The supervisor says I should just set a no encrpyted password in WR and read it and it will be enough, because its just prototype what I'm doing now. I can already do what he said, but I don't want to stop after spending more than two weeks, that's why I asking you to help.

Comment: My advice remains the same as in the previous comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would also advise so in your place. But for beginner which is under the pressure of time yet, it is not so easy. Nevertheless many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally `TBitRange` should be a subrange, e.g.:

```
type
  TBitRange = 0..31;
```

The subrange gets enforced at compile time.
Java does not have subranges, so there is no equivalent.

You can declare the function as follows:

```
public static int SetBit(final int Value, final byte Bit)
{
    assert bit >= 0;
    assert bit <= 31;   
    final int shift = 1 << Bit;
    return Value | shift;
}
```

Unfortunately the assert is only checked at runtime.

However in your earlier deleted question you defined TBitRange as:

```
type
  TBitRange = Byte;
```

The `byte` type in Java is signed, whereas the `byte` type in Delphi is unsigned. There is no unsigned 8 bit int in Java. For the purpose of the question though a signed Java byte will work just fine.

**About shl**
Delphi's `shl`/`shr` follows x86 sematics and is thus wrapped around at 32 for integers. For this reason the `mod BitsPerInteger` part is pointless. The language already performs this operation as per its specification (i.e. `someint shl 32` is a no-op).

[Java does the same thing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) so in Java the mod is also not needed.

> **what is this function doing exactly?**

Just like it says on the label: it sets a bit.
An integer is a 32-bit type.
This means that there are 32 bits (on/off switches aka booleans) inside the variable.
These are numbered from 0 to 31.
If you want to conserve space you can use this fact to store 32 booleans in a single integer, instead of having to use 32 variables. This squeezes 32 bytes into 4 bytes; an 8x reduction.
In Delphi we usually utilize a `set of ...` for this. Java does not have sets, so you'll have to resort to using a bitfield instead.

A bitfield is really a compressed `array of boolean`, but because there is no array syntax for bitfields you'll have to use functions instead.

```
BoolArray[8]:= true -> BitField:= SetBit(BitField,8);
if BoolArray[8] then ... -> if GetBit(BitField,8) then ...
```

Obviously in Delphi you could emulate this using properties:

```
TBitField = record
private
  FStorage: integer;
  function GetBit(Index: TBitRange): boolean;
  procedure SetBit(Index: TBitRange; const Value: boolean);
public
  property IsTrue[Index: TBitRange]: boolean read GetBit write SetBit;
end;
```

`Properties` is another thing Java does not have, so in Java it is really impossible to do this fake array trick.

Comment: You probably forgot about `mod BitsPerInteger` - this operation ensures that shift argument is  in valid range. Moreover, this is redundant action in Delphi because shift always is taken by modulo bitsize of int type (like asm, don't know about Java behavior)

Comment: TBitRange appears to be whatever you want it to be. Why do you think it is that? If it really is that then the mod is pointless. It's pointless anyway I guess.

Comment: No that's in the language specification. Read the documentation. It's true that the reflects the original hardware but that doesn't mean that the behaviour is different on different hardware. For reasons that behaviour is now enshrined.

Comment: I cannot believe that you are prepared to quote a deleted question. I don't think it's a good idea to do that. We should stand together and insist on good quality questions. Don't you care about the quality of this site?

Comment: The question is the problem and it is still broken

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you very much for your effort. Although I was not registered here, this page helped very much. And it would be unpossible without user like you. But when I asked a question, it was then disliked and I couldn't make no more question for three days. I've corrected it with my Java code with some commented places where I have problems. I think its not the best way to handle like this. You can also give chance to user to correct his answer and to try ask it in another way.

Comment: @When your question is down voted that tells you that you need to improve it. Do that in an edit. Clearly you are new to this site and don't fully understand how it works. All the more reason to read the articles at the [help] very carefully. Make that your next task.

Answer (score 1):

As the mod op. is redundant and SHL is x86 semantics:

```
function SetBitSimple(const Value: Integer; i: byte): Integer;
begin
  Result:= Value OR (1 shl i);
end;
```

writeln(inttobin(SetBitSimple(152,12)));

> 00000000000000000001000010011000